# auto generating sitemap.xml for my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-2, sitemap

Can anybody please guide me on how to auto generate a sitemap.xml file for my website using an ashx handler?

Comment: Can you please give us a ASHX URL example you have in your MVC.NET project? If you cannot do it with WGET, a database or a routing map database how can we help?

Comment: @JeremyThompson this question was posted 2 years ago i should have deleted it by now ... but it has an answer so as long as the answer is there i cannot really delete the question

Comment: irony, i earned a popular question badge on a question with 1 DV :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each unique `aspx` file on your site corresponds to a single page you will want to traverse the files and the folders within your site using the [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) objects in [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29kt2zfk.aspx) namespace filtering for `*.aspx`. You may want to include other possible files if you serve `*.html` or `*.pdf` etc.

Create a recursive function that iterates through all the files in a directory and then calls itself on all the subdirectories in the directory.

As you walk the directory tree simply generate a node in sitemap.xml for each item. Do this with [String.Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Your [sitemap.xml structure](http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php) is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Append the URLs in separate `<loc/>` elements.

Comment: This is a very bad assumption. What about many "pages" that differ only by querystring. What about routing. What about MVC?. What about password protected pages that should not be listed. Files <> Pages

Comment: @CarlosMunoz yes I did think of that but this was just meant to be a suggestion of a place to start and not a complete solution. If your site is showing hugely different pages just using the querystring then I would assume there is some generation of meta information and pages titles based on querystring values. If that were the case I'm not sure they would need help with the sitemap as they'd already have some structure to work with but the question was quite vauge.

Comment: If we have hugely different pages we could also map in some [multiple sitemap files](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index) and list each of them in the Sitemap index file that specified in robot.txt.